# SharePoint 2013 multi people refiner showing as a single line with semicolumns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, refiner, refinement-panel

I have a Multi user field in my site collection. SharePoint has created a crawled property named ows_MyUserField. I have created a managed property MyUserField with multiple values set to true. I have created some items with multiple users in the MyUserField field. I have run a full crawl. When I set this field as a refiner in my refinement panel I see all the values on 1 line seperated by a ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed there is also a automatic crawled property called “ows_q_USER_MyUserField”. When I map a new managed property on this crawled property I do get a correct filter. The only problem is that the user are shown in a not so friendly format.

[image]

I have created a new refinement filter display template to display the username that is between the |. For the first two items in the refiner this won't do the job but in my case all users are shown like the third filter in the image.

I have shared my display template here:

https://gist.github.com/waaromikniet/b99ef686312b5dbab5cfa8791f3d8f41#file-filter_user-html

On line 266 I created a js function to get the name of the user between the | | ( in my case this is always correct, in the image example it won't work for the first 2)